# Are there different EPSG codes for 6 digit, 7 digit and 8 digit UTM Zone32 coordinate systems (CRS)?

Tags: coordinate-system

I get data sent to me in various flavours of EPSG:25832. Unfortunately, everyone thinks that their own EPSG:25832 is the correct one. Some send data with the 32 at the front, others with just a 2, and most with the 32 left off and only the False easting of 500,000m

So, which is the correct EPSG:25832? 6 digit, 7 digit or 8 digit? ArcGIS recognises all, but have also various names for them too. E.g in Projection / National Grids / Germany I see 4 different "ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 32N.prj" Files for 6 digits, 7 digits, and 8 digits and one without a suffix which is also just the 6 Digit CRS. Also to make things worse there is also ETRS 1989 UTM Zone N32" (((!!! N32 instead of 32N !!!)))with the 32 at the front again!

In Projected / UTM / Europe/ there is also "ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 32N.prj" which doesn´t begin with 32.

Can anyone standardize this for me?  Has sometime tampered with my CRS Directory in order to confuse me?

Answer (score 4):

This **is** standardized ;-)

See this explanation in German: http://www.lgn.niedersachsen.de/download/71484/Massgeschneiderte_EPSG-Codes_fuer_GIS-Anwendungen.pdf

The official code for UTM 32N is EPSG:25832

```
+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

The  German Surveying authorities have requested special EPSG codes with the zone numer in front of the Easting coordinate, like EPSG:4647

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=32500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

You see that the false Easting is extended by 32000000 to get the preceeding 32.

If you have data with a preceeding 2, it rather might be old DHDN Gauss-Krueger zone 2 EPSG:31466

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs
```

with the false Easting extended by 2000000.

My examples are proj.4 definition strings, but Arcgis WKT should look similar, except for the DHDN datum shift.

Comment: The N32 is for a ProjCRS that has axis order easting-northing. Its name in EPSG is now: ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N) and we're (esri) behind-the-times. Traditionally, Germany has used northing-easting axis ordering, but some authorities have requested easting-northing order.

Comment: The northing-easting CRS are defined with EPSG:5651 to 5653. But since GIS software usually uses Easting-Northing, I did not mention them.